# How to test a ternary operator with Jasmine in javascript

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am trying to test a piece of my code using Jasmine, but I am stuck on which method to use and how to go about testing this particular function. Here is my code:

```
const foodInfoToggle1 = () => {
    const foodInfo = document.querySelector('#first');
    foodInfo.style.display === "none" ? foodInfo.style.display = "block" :  foodInfo.style.display = "none";
}
```

This function encompasses toggle functionality and is assigned to a button. Once the button is clicked, the function runs to see if the paragraph is set to 'none'. If it is, then it switches to 'block' and vice versa.  As you can see, my function is not accepting any parameters so I am finding it difficult to use test cases. How exactly would I go about testing this type of code using Jasmine.

Comment: You should know what state it starts out in.  Otherwise you can perform your querySelector in your test and change it to an initial state.  Then call your method.  After it is done, verify that the state has toggled.

Comment: Then have a second test that puts the initial state in the other state.  Call the method.  Verify it's in the other toggled state afterwards.

Comment: This logic could also be reduced to `foodInfo.style.display = { none: 'block', block: 'none' }[foodInfo.style.display];`.  Even shorter if you stored the `.style` in the variable instead of the Element

Comment: Be careful. You should not test the ternary operator. Instead, you should test the `foodInfoToggle1` function. Define in words what the result of calling this function should be and test **that**, not the implementation details.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. Understandable. So since my function starts out with a display = 'none' I assume my expectations should look something like this  expect(foodInfoToggle1()).toBe('block')

Comment: No, because your function does not return anything.  Your test, as your code is written, has to grab the element being manipulated and verify its state is changed as expected.

Comment: @azaria.dee There are two tests here: 1. When '#first' is not displayed, calling `foodInfoToggle1()` causes it to be displayed. 2. When '#first' is displayed, calling `foodInfoToggle1()` hides it. You cannot do either of these tests from teh return value of `foodInfoToggle1` because it returns `undefined`. Instead, you will have to inspect the dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
describe('foodInfoToggle1', () => {
  let element;
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    element = document.createElement('span');
    
    spyOn(document, 'querySelector').and.callFake(selector => {
        if (selector === '#first') return element;
    });
  });
  
  it('Should change the display from none to block', () => {
      element.style.display = 'none';
      
      foodInfoToggle1();
      
      expect(element.style.display).toEqual('block');
  });
  
  it('Should change the display from block to none', () => {
      element.style.display = 'block';
      
      foodInfoToggle1();
      
      expect(element.style.display).toEqual('none');
  });
});
```

I didn't find a quick way to include jasmine in the post, so hopefully all my syntax is correct.

The idea here being for each test, we create a dummy element and mockout the querySelector method.  If it is called with the expected selector, return the dummy element.

Then for each of our tests, we put the style display in our expected initial value.  We then call the method, and verify that the style display changed.

Comment: Thank you! I see what you mean. Now I know what to do for future cases.